# mysql query restricting on multiple periods

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to write a mysql query to detect *three* or more periods in a email string. Example

```
gr.em.test.t@domain.com
```

I'm thinking I could use some sort of mysql like query, but I'm not sure how to best write the regex. Any thoughts?

```
SELECT MyColumn
From MyTable
WHERE MyColumn like
```

Comment: @Barmar This isn't a duplicate of the question you linked.  The question you linked is asking how to count how many occurrences of a given string are in a column.  The OP for this question is asking how to return rows where a certain column has X number occurrences of a string.  While similar, it's not a duplicate as the question you linked doesn't actually answer the OP's question.

Comment: @michael I agree, this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: OK, although if you can count them, you can use `WHERE <count> >= 3`.

Comment: True. I definitely agree with you that question could be helpful to the OP.  I just felt it didn't fully answer their question.

Answer (score 1):

No need for any type of regular expression, simply use the `LIKE` clause like you have, so you're on the right track.  The following query should give you what you want:

`SELECT MyColumn FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn LIKE "%.%.%.%";`

Comment: how can I make it >= 3 though? I'm having an issue with scammers cluttering my database with these bogus emails, so I'd like to clean them up.

Comment: @CodeJunkie The query I provided will handle `>= 3`.  The `%` act as a wildcard, which will match periods as well.  There has to be at least 3 periods for it to match, but it also matches rows with more than 3 periods.

Comment: Okay great, I was thinking it would match only 3 for some reason. Thanks.